# Remove a file named '

Tags: bash, rm

I accidentally created a file named `'`. Is there a simple way to delete this in bash? Unfortunately, there is already default behavior for `rm '`.

Comment: can you post the command that created it? that could also give a clue to delete it

Comment: vim "'"  was the command i used

Comment: so `rm "'"` would have worked too ;)

Comment: If you want to delete your question, you can do so yourself. You should see a "delete" button under it. However, please don't let a couple of downvotes get you down. We've all done silly things and we were all newbs before becoming experts. I think the downvoters didn't realize just how hard it is to search for special characters on search engines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using double quotes around `'`:

```
rm "'"
```

Using single quote, and escaping:

```
rm \'
```

Comment: `rm \'` also works

Comment: @JosephR. Actually was in the middle of incorporating this :)

Comment: ...and in the general case `rm -i ?` could help, since `?` is a wildcard representing any a single character

Comment: Just to have some other option: `rm $'\''` also works. ;-)